# Pass HTML Code Entity into SwiftUI Text view

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to use the symbol pi (HTML:  `&#960;`) in a Text view. How can I use the pi symbol as the value of the Text view?

I tried using `NSAttributedString` but it causes certain errors. I also tried just passing in raw HTML code but that doesn't work, probably because of encoding reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Text(String("\u{03C0}"))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean in `Text` then we can use unicode symbols, like

```
Text("\u{1D70B}")
```

[image: demo]